# Need to align a button next to text box in form-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image: form-group]

I am trying to use form-group and form a structure like given but the button doesn't seem to align with the textbox.

My current code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <span for="artistname" class="control-label">Enter Artist Name</span></br>
        <input id="artistname" type="text" ng-modal="artist1" class="form-control text_element_width" placeholder="Enter Artist Name." />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-click="addArtistChoice()">Add Artist</button>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="artist in artists" class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-modal="{{artist.artistName}}" class="form-control text_element_width" placeholder="Enter Artist Name.">
        <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-click="removeArtistChoice(artist)" /></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.  The first one would be to combine `.form-horizontal` with `.form-group` and the Bootstrap Grid system.  That results in a fully-defined button adjacent to the input field.

But Bootstrap has a component for `.input-group` that allows you to affix the button directly to the input; so that's an option too!  Examples of both follow:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-horizontal">
 <label for="artistname" class="control-label">Enter Artist Name</label>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
   <input id="artistname" type="text" ng-modal="artist1" class="form-control text_element_width" placeholder="Enter Artist Name." />
  </div>
 
  <div class="col-xs-3">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-click="addArtistChoice()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Artist</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<hr />

<label for="artistname" class="control-label">Enter Artist Name</label>
<div class="input-group">
 <input id="artistname" type="text" ng-modal="artist1" class="form-control text_element_width" placeholder="Enter Artist Name." />
 <div class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addArtistChoice()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Artist</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please note that in addition to the two examples, I made changes to how you're calling your Glyph Icon.